# Run multiple commands in individual terminal tabs

Tags: mac, terminal

I'm developping some rails apps on Mac 10.8.5, and often times, I have a terminal window with a few tabs running commands:
rails s
rails c
mongod
bundle exec guard start

each of which in its own tab. when I switch project, I have to close them all and when I return to this project, I have to rerun these commands all over again. Is there a shortcut or another terminal tool that I can use to run them all in a prepackaged way?

Thank you!

Comment: In linux when you use `&` it sends the program to background and you can bring it to foreground using `fg`. I think the same applies in mac. Just run `commandtoberun &` and `fg pid` to bring it to foreground

Comment: Hi Emab, that did work for running them all at once, but I also need them separate terminal tabs for reading the logs each of them generates. Any ideas?

Comment: you may pipe the output of each command into a file and use `tail -f logname` to see the log.

Answer (score 0):

To run the commands in the bachground you can use the `&` operator. For example you can use

```
myfirstcommand &
```

and it gives you the `pid` of the process.

If you want to have the log of each command, you can pipe the output of each command, and use the `tail` command to watch the log whenever you want to:

```
myfirstcommand  & >> myfirstlog
mysecondcommand & >> mysecondlog
```

and whenever you want to watch the log of each one you can use the tail like following:

```
tail -f myfirstlog
```

or

```
tail -numberoflines myfirstlog
```